# mvc 4 - c# - Entity Framework - Metadata using edmx file

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using Entity Framework edmx. When I update the edmx I lose my metadata.How do you create and use metadata properties (that are not real fields).

Comment: Use view models, apply your attributes to the view model properties and map between you view model and data model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Metadata folder in the project where is the edmx. Create a class with the name of your entity as bellow: And within the same file create another class with the name of your entity with the "metadata" extension  (MyEntityMetadata).

```
namespace MyNameSpace.DataAccess //You need to use the same namespace of edmx entities files
{
    [MetadataType(typeof(MyEntityMetaData))]
    public partial class MyEntity //This is possible because entities files using partial class
    {
        [NotMapped] //System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema
        public int MyProperty { get; set; }


       //more properties...
     }

    public class UsuarioMetaData
    {
        [Display(ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Global), Name = "MyFieldLabel")]
        public int MyField { get; set; }

       //More fields
     }

}
```